# Remote methods, central management of remoting

Tags: .net, remoting, projects-and-solutions

First of all let me explain what I want to do. I want to devolop a server that will listen to client requests. My server has a modular architecture.

For example, there is an Offer module. The Offer Module has 4 projects: Action, Message, Entity, and Query. The Query project generally contains the classes which contain remote methods.

First question: How can I develop my server such that it manages all transactions, queries centrally. I mean, all the requests should be routed from this central managing class to the requested module and its remote method. I need your ideas.

Second: Let's say that in my Offer module, the Query project's ProductQuery class has 10 methods but 5 of them are remote. The CustomerQuery class has 15 method, 3 of them are remote methods. I want to obtain all remote methods in one query project (for example in OfferModule's Query project, or Accounting module's Query project) to one assembly for remoting. For example in one OfferQuery assembly.

I need your help. Thank you!

Comment: Concerning your first question, you are being far too unspecific to get reasonable answers. We would need to know what frameworks you are using for your server component, and what typical, concrete queries would look like. Please provide more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll leave your first question unanswered, because it cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

---

**My understanding of your second question:**

First, let me try to understand your server architecture's basic layout:

```
  +--------+  1     1..n  +--------+  1    1..n  +---------+
  | Server |<>------------| Module |<>-----------| Project |
  +--------+              +--------+             +---------+
```

"There's one server, which has or consists of 1 or more modules, each of which has or consists of several projecs." I took this straight from your question. The first thing I don't understand here is, are we talking about run-time components, or about the layout of your source code solution?

More concretely, you seem to have this hierarchy of modules, projects, and classes:

```
Server
|
+---- Accounting (module)
|     ¦
|     ? (projects)
|
+---- Offer (module)
¦     |
?     +---- Action (project)
      |
      +---- Message (project)
      |
      +---- Entity (project)
      |
      +---- Query (project)
            |
            +---- ProductQuery (class)
            |
            +---- CustomerQuery (class)
            ¦
            ?
```

And if I understand you correctly, you now want to gather all "remote" query methods from e.g. `ProductQuery` and `CustomerQuery` inside a common `OfferQuery` class... is this correct?

---

**Proposed direction towards a solution for your second question:**

Now, given that you have not provided much detail about the technologies and frameworks that you use, I'll also stay somewhat vague:

I think what you're trying to do isn't a good approach. Why? Because you're going to put completely unrelated things into one single class, based on the idea that they're all "query" methods. But they query very different things: e.g. `Offers`, `Products`, `Customers`. That's not a good object-oriented design because, well, it's not "domain-oriented". It's query-oriented.

I think you would do well to develop a clean object (domain) model. Design classes around the logical entities in your system (e.g. the already mentioned offers, products, accounts, customers, etc.). Keep the corresponding classes completely free of query methods.

Now, where do the queries go? You could look at object-relational model mappers (OR/M) for this task. Hibernate (or with .NET, NHibernate) or Microsoft's Entity Framework for .NET are good options. They will map your domain model onto a relational database and do all the creating, querying, updating and deleting in the DB for you.

Comment: You briefly describe my projects architecture.But I actually define clean object model.All the queries about offer will be in oferr modules operation class.You are right sometimes I will use customer query in offer module but all common queries is in one repository class in core module.Becouse of my limited english I cant explain in details.My operation class in one module gets specified message ,executes it sotre to DB or vice versa.I understand what you offer me.I studied about  entity framwork.Bu for this project I hve to use this kind of architecture.Thank you a lot for your care

Comment: @Trusik, if you cannot or don't want to use something like Entity Framework, then I would still urge you *not* to put together unrelated query classes into one single query class. Keep one query class per domain entity (as you have it now). Instead, try to remoev all methods that are not query-related from your query classes and put them somewhere else.

Comment: @stakx.I am not yet design architecture completely.I am open to your offers.I understand what you say and I will try much more clean domain model as you say.Is there any way collect all remote  atributed methods in one dll on build?

Comment: @Trusik: There is *absolutely no need* to somehow re-organise methods in DLLs. Simply put your methods in the right projects *before you compile* your solution, and they will end up in the right DLL. **Thinking about DLLs is not a helpful perspective**: Later on, you won't maintain DLLs but source code! **Therefore, clean up your source code**: Remove a method here and re-insert it in the right place. That'll make your code better organised and therefore easier to understand and navigate. In your case, attributes cannot and will not bring order to chaos and are the wrong way to do this.

Comment: @stakx.I will seperate phisically as you say.I will write detailed architecture here for your modifications.Thanx a lot